# Creating an abstract class which implements a generic interface

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an abstract class which extends and also implements a generic interface.

```
type ComponentType<TT extends Lightning.Component.TemplateSpec> =  Lightning.Component.ImplementTemplateSpec<TT>

export default abstract class Component<
        T extends Lightning.Component.TemplateSpecLoose = Lightning.Component.TemplateSpecLoose
    >
    extends Lightning.Component<T>
    implements ComponentType<T>
{
   ...
}
```

The issue is I am getting an error `A class can only *implement* an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.` for the part of the implement.

The expectation is that I can create extended classes like this

```
class Playback
    extends Component<PlaybackSpec>
    implements Spec<PlaybackSpec> 
    {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that others can copy and paste into their own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  My IDE has no idea what `Lightning` or most of the other stuff here might be, so it's hard to even begin to make a suggestion.  My *guess* is that what you're calling an "interface" really isn't one (at least it's not an `interface`) but without more information I can't be sure.